# SSIS Running Powershell with Custom Functions (psm1's)

Tags: sql-server, function, powershell, ssis

Let me start by saying I'm not new to Powershell, but I *am* new to custom functions.

So I have created a custom function (with a single cmd-let) to handle logging to our db. It works like a charm. Let's call it write-myfunction.

At first, It worked when I ran it in ISE but then wouldn't work on the scheduler. I fixed that by adding the hosted folder with the PSM1 to my PATH powershell variables. Boom. Now it works on scheduler. Great. Wonderful. Moving on.

Problem NOW is that we're running SSIS (Same GA User) and having SSIS call the powershell script, it doesn't seem to be finding my psm1. I get
"write-myfunction isn't a valid name of a cmd-let blahblah"

Worth Noting: I have my function folder hosted on our network share in a place with totally open permissions (I have it backing up on the daily and alarms, so I'll get alarm bells if something in that folder changes)

Questions!

1. Is keeping a central repository of custom modules on some other server a smart move? Should I just deploy a copy of that folder into c:\program files\powershell to every computer instead via GP?
2. What am I missing on this SSIS thing? I figure if I run as an AD GA account, it should have access to the folder with the script, and the fact that the SSIS package is running on the local system that I edited the PATH variables to encompass my hosted modules folder right? So.. like.. what do?

*edit
Here is where I was able to fix the first issue:
[image: PSModulePath addition]

And here's me confirming I can GCI to the hosted files in a powershell window

[image]

Comment: I think you mean _modules_, not functions. Note that it isn't the PATH environment variable that matters for module auto-loading, but the `PSModulePath` variable. I don't know how SSIS invokes PowerShell, but have you verified that it can access these network locations (e.g., with `Get-ChildItem`)?

Comment: PowerShell has separate 32-bit and 64-bit execution environments. SSIS packages can be run in separate 32-bit and 64-bit run times. Is your module installed in both PowerShell environments?

Comment: @mklement0 I added where I put the PSModulePath variable.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It is not, I don't think? I kinda thought adding the UNC path to the hosted folder would install it for both? (See my edit above) is that not correct?

Comment: As for the terminology confusion. Custom _functions_ can be defined via dot-sourced _script_ files (`*.ps1`) or via _modules_ (stand-alone `*.psm1` files in the simplest case, but more typically _folders_ with a module _manifest_ (`*.psd1`), _possibly_ with an attendant `*.psm1` file, but only if the module is implemented using _PowerShell code_).

Comment: Given that you can access the UNC path, what happens if you include an explicit `Import-Module -Verbose <pathToPsm1>` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: **Yes!** Keep your modules somewhere central that gets backed up, and consider adding them to a git repository to track changes over time. Be aware of the permissions if you share the location with others!

Also note that if the remote server is not a "trusted location" for powershell, you may have to manage your execution policy settings and/or `Unblock-File` before running your scripts.

2: (Assuming you are running your SSIS packages on a server) SSIS generally runs commands locally on the server you're connected to. You'll want to make sure that server can connect to your shared location **and** that the service account running the server instance has access.

What does your SSIS task look like? I would use an Execute Process task with:

```
Executable: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments:  -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command '\\path\to\script.ps1'
```

Where `script.ps1` contains:

```
# Import your custom modules:
Import-Module '\\path\to\module.psm1'

# Run your custom functions
Write-MyFunction -foo X -bar Y
```

[Check out this write-up](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6172/execute-powershell-script-from-ssis-package/) for more details on the package itself

If you continue to have issues running the script, try saving the script locally on the server. Windows has some restrictions on second-hop remoting that can make accessing file shares through SSIS difficult.

Comment: Execution Policy did it!

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I should note for others, I ALSO added in the import-module, where with other scripts I didn't need to do that before because the module would pull just fine from the PATH directory. So that may have actually been the ticket.

Either way, a combination of the two seems to have done it.